# Angular ng-repeating json fields with hyphen

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<span ng-repeat="doc in docs">
   <p>{{doc.posted-Time}}</p>
```

All I get is a 0 instead of the actual value in the json. Is there a way to escape the '-'?

Normally I would do `doc['posted-Time']` and that would do the trick, but with angular it is not working.

any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: {{doc["posted-Time"]}} works fine  http://plnkr.co/edit/cG3Kq4lLYKJ64wdUVmD4?p=preview

Comment: It works fine indeed: http://plnkr.co/edit/7miU77tGG1zGyXGZ0pYC?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, yes it does work. Going to delete the question, thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember you can use bracket notation as well.

```
<span ng-repeat="doc in docs">
   <p>{{doc["posted-Time"]}}</p>
```

Comment: The question explicitly stated that didn't work for him (not sure why).

Comment: Ah my bad. I jumped to that answer.

Comment: Not sure what I was doing, you're right it works fine. So much wasted time..no wonder I couldn't find anything about it.